# Lists garbage collection

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, erlang

If I do the following:

```
List2 = [V || V <- List1, ...]
```

It seems that the List2 refers to the List1 and erlang:garbage_collect() doesn't clear memory. How is it possible to create a new list without references and discard the old?

Comment: Why do you need a new list?

Comment: I have many running gen_servers with list in state and I want to periodically clean them from expired items to reduce memory consumption.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not keeping some reference to List1 somewhere, and that you are actually filtering out any elements so that List2 is smaller than List1?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that List2 is smaller than List1.
If I do 
List2 = [binary_to_term(binary:copy(term_to_binary(V))) || V <- List1, ...]
I get desired result, but it looks ugly and I want to try something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM is supposed to manage the garbage collecting. If you use a gen_server, or if you use a "home made" server_loop(State), you should have always the same pattern:

```
server_loop(State) ->
   A = somefunc(State),
   B = receive
          mesg1 -> func1(...);
          ...
       after Timeout ->
          func2(...)
       end,
   NewState = func3(...),
   server_loop(NewState).
```

As long as a process is alive, executing this loop, the VM will allocate and manage memory areas to store all needed information (variables, message queue...+ some margin) As far as I know, there is some spare memory allocated to the process, and if the VM does not try to recover the memory very fast after it has been released, but if you force a garbage collecting, using erlang:garbage_collect(Pid) you can verify that the memory is free - see example bellow.

```
startloop() -> spawn(?MODULE,loop,[{lists:seq(1,1000),infinity}]).

loop(endloop) -> ok;
loop({S,T}) ->
    NewState = receive
        biglist -> {lists:seq(1,5000000),T};
        {timeout,V} -> {S,V};
        sizelist -> io:format("Size of the list = ~p~n",[length(S)]),
                            {S,T};
        endloop -> endloop
    after T ->
        L = length(S) div 2,
        {lists:seq(1,L),T}
    end,
    loop(NewState).
    %% Here, NewState is a copy of State or a totally new data, depending on the
    %% received message. In general, for performance consideration it can be 
    %% interesting to take care of the function used to avoid big copies, 
    %% and allow the compiler optimize the beam code 
    %% [H|Q] rather than Q ++ [H] to add a term to a list for example
```

and the results in the VM:

```
2> P = lattice:startloop().
<0.57.0>
...
6> application:start(sasl).  
....
ok
7> application:start(os_mon).
...
ok
...
11> P ! biglist.
biglist
...
```

**% get_memory_data() -> {Total,Allocated,Worst}.**

```
14> memsup:get_memory_data().
{8109199360,5346488320,{<0.57.0>,80244336}}
...
23> P ! {timeout,1000}.             
{timeout,1000}
24> memsup:get_memory_data().
{8109199360,5367361536,{<0.57.0>,80244336}}
```

**the worst case is the loop process: {<0.57.0>,80244336}**

```
...
28> P ! sizelist.            
Size of the list = 0
sizelist
...
31> P ! {timeout,infinity}.
{timeout,infinity}
32> P ! biglist.                    
biglist
33> P ! sizelist.          
Size of the list = 5000000
sizelist
...
36> P ! {timeout,1000}.      
{timeout,1000}
37> memsup:get_memory_data().
{8109199360,5314289664,{<0.57.0>,10770968}}
```

**%% note the garbage collecting in the previous line: {<0.57.0>,10770968}**

```
38> P ! sizelist.            
sizelist
Size of the list = 156250
39> memsup:get_memory_data().
{8109199360,5314289664,{<0.57.0>,10770968}}
...
46> P ! sizelist.            
Size of the list = 0
sizelist
47> memsup:get_memory_data().
{8109199360,5281882112,{<0.57.0>,10770968}}
...
50> erlang:garbage_collect(P).
true
51> memsup:get_memory_data(). 
{8109199360,5298778112,{<0.51.0>,688728}}
```

**%% after GC, the process <0.57.0> is no more the worst case**

Answer (score 2):

In any language with garbage collection you simply need to 'lose' all references to a piece of data before it can be garbage collected. Simply returning from the function that generates the original list, while not storing it in any other 'persistent' location (e.g. the process dictionary), should allow the memory to be reclaimed.

Comment: @P_A The elements in `List1` will automatically be removed by the garbage collector when there are no references to them. The whole point of garbage collection is not have to explicitly worry about removing objects, not have to worry about if they are alive or not and who is to remove them. In Erlang, as in most languages with a garbage collector, there is no explicit `free`. Having an explicit `free` is always fraught with danger. In this case the system actually does know better than you do.

Answer (score 0):

If you create new list like this, the new list will have elements from the first one, some elements will be shared between both the lists. And if you throw the first list away, shared elements will still be reachable from the new list and won't count as garbage.

How do you check if the first list is garbage collected? Do you test this in erlang console? The console stores results of evaluation each expression that may be the cause you don't see the list garbage collected.

Comment: No, I tested behaviour of the garbage collector on real application, not in the console. I used htop to monitor memory consumption.
Is there a way to create list without elements that will be shared between both the lists?

Comment: I don't understand why would you need this. You'll have the same elements using the same of even more memory.

The only useful case is if you have one huge binary and you match a few small parts of it. In that case the new sub-binaries will be only pointers to the main binary with offset and length parameters and thus your binary will not be garbage collected too. For this you have `binary:copy/1`.

Comment: If L1 = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5] and L2 = [A1] then I want the elements A2-A5 has been removed from memory.

Comment: You don't need to copy elements, in this case they must be garbage collected. Again, what kind of elements are in the list? Are there parts of some big binary?